# set up python emacs environment mac os x

Tags: python, macos, emacs

I have followed this tutorial for setting up a python emacs enviroment.

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/05/my-emacs-python-environment/

I'm able to get python mode for emacs and syntax highlighting but when I try to use
rope and ropemacs for example the command C-c d for the documentiation I get that the command is not defined

rope and ropemacs where installed with easy install and my .emacs file looks like
Am'I missing something??

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
 (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook)
 (provide 'init_python)


(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(eval-after-load "pymacs"
   '(add-to-list 'pymacs-load-path ~/.emacs.d/vendor/pymacs-0.24-beta2"))

(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)


(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/auto-complete-1.2")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/vendor/auto-complete-1.2/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your ropeemacs dir into the load path, so that EMACS can find the package and load those commands for you

```
(setq load-path (cons "/PATH-OF-ROPEEMACS"      load-path))
```

to be honest, I don't think rope emacs is that useful for me, it slows down the emacs startup quite a lot, but the benefit is not that obvious. when I want to look up issues, I simply go SO.